# Best practice building a parser library

Tags: c#

I am building a parser library which is able to parse standardized file formats. If parsing fails the user should be able to get log information about why the parsing failed (i.e. where the file differes from the standard).

I am not sure how to implement this, I guess it might be handy to have an event which is fired during parse time for the logs, but also storing the log information is a good idea.

Should I implement the parsing with the factory pattern or on an object basis?

Factory pattern:

```
FileModel.ParserInformation += OnParserInformation;
var myModel = FileModel.Parse(@"C:\temp\myfile.file");
FileModel.ParserInformation -= OnParserInformation;

//Parsing failed
if(myModel == null)
{
    // Handle case 
}
else
{
    // Continue work
}
```

Pro:

- User does not get an empty object he cannot work on

Cons:

- Parsing information is static, event might not correlate to the
  actual parsing when multiple parser are run at the same time
- "Offline" log is not available when parsing fails

Object basis:

```
var myModel = new FileModel();
myModel.ParserInformation += OnParserInformation;
myModel.Parse(@"C:\temp\myfile.file");
myModel.ParserInformation -= OnParserInformation;

if(myModel.HasData)
{
    // Continue work
}
else
{
    // Handle errors
    var logs = myModel.GetLogInformation();
}
```

Pro:

- Offline Log available
- Object based event handling

Cons:

- Object can be instantied without any "content" inside

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of files are you trying to parse? It will be next to impossible to build anything remotely "general purpose" when it comes to parsing even "standardized" file formats. Some of them require full-blown parser (like XML or HTML), some can be parsed by means of reading records of known sizes (think Protobuf-serialized content), some require bit-by-bit manipulations.

Comment: I am parsing industry standard files, basically they just contain structured text. Underlying parser is built with ANTLR.